# kinesis data firehose log data is in encrypted form

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

**strong text**I create a aws Cross-Account Log Data Sharing with Subscriptions.
By follow this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CrossAccountSubscriptions.html)

After create kinesis stream create **Kinesis Data Firehose delivery streams** to save logs in s3 bucket.

logs files creating in S3 bucket but in **encrypted form** .

[image]

And at sender side no KMS key id ..

[image]

How can i see the logs..

Also not able to decrypt in base64 manually..

**Updated:**
I found that logs store in S3 bucket have **"Content-Type application/octet-stream"**. when i update content-type to **"text/plain"** ..
is there any way set in bucket level content type or configure in kinesis data stream or firehose

[image]

**Is there any way to set content-type kinesis stream or set the default content-type for s3 folder?**

Answer (score 3):

The data you posted *appears* to be compressed (I'd need a short file sample to be able to say that for certain). If I were you I'd look into compression settings for the log stream.

Here, it references some different compressions available for data: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/record-format-conversion.html

In a pinch, if you save those data in a file and give it the ".gz" extension, does the file become readable? (I'm not too hopeful since it says that the default compression scheme is Snappy and not GZIP, and I might be mistaken but I think I see a ZIP preamble after some kind of header in your screenshot).